# <p:selectOneMenu> getting null on submit/next

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces wizard. During wizard flow all parameters saved correctly . However `<p:selectOneMenu>` items getting NULL on submit.Also on 'back', it will not show what I have selected. Same for `<p:selectManyMenu>` also. Any solution ?

Here is the code snippets.I'm using primefaces-3.0.M3 and jsf2.

```
<h:outputText value="Employee Status" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="employeeStatus"value="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.employeeStatus.title}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Permanent" itemValue="Permanent" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Contract" itemValue="Contract" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Part-Time" itemValue="Part-Time" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Training" itemValue="Training" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message id="employeeStatusId" for="employeeStatus" />
```

This is in a `<p:wizard>` tab, while clicking next button or submit button, the itemValues getting null.Sorry for the re-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you deleted the previous post?

Anyway, firstly, you should upgrade to `Primefaces 3.0.M4`!

Secondly, it would be better to use a list along with `f:selectItems` and all those String values to be stored in a list(this way you have **more control** over what's in the list and what should the list return), but if you want to stick with `f:selectItem` try using it with the enclosing tag (it may be a bug without it):

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Permanent" itemValue="Permanent" ></f:selectItem>
```

Also, I repeat myself, upgrade to Primefaces 3.0.M4!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by using primefaces AJAX

```
<p:ajax update="employeeStatus" listener="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.employeeStatusAjax}" />
```

inside my `</p:selectOneMenu>` and I check/process this in side `employeeStatusAjax()`.

Comment: Even you found out where's the problem, it's not a nice thing to unaccept an answer that helped you in a way or a another...

Comment: I think it made us misleaded, I have the same problem and now I didn't find the answer helpful